# Getting JSON data as QueryDict

Tags: jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework and have this code to do a PUT call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/order/'+orderid+'/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { book: true }
});
```

and this is the view that handles that:

```
@api_view(['PUT', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def api_orderbook(request, orderid):
    logger.debug(request.data)
    if request.method == 'PUT' and request.data.get("book") == True:
         ... do stuff ...
```

But, the `request.data.get("book")` is not a boolean, but a string:

```
<QueryDict: {u'book': [u'true']}>
```

When I use `JSON.stringify({ book: true })` in my Ajax call, it is even worse:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"book":true}': [u'']}>
```

How can I get the Javascript object as a correct Python `QueryDict` in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the `data` field as BooleanField in model.py, then you should convert the bool value from true/false to integer 0/1 before sending the ajax request. Here is the sample code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/order/'+orderid+'/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { book: 1 } // 1 stands for true in BooleanField
});
```

Actually, the BooleanField will store 0/1 integer in the database instead of true/false.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the model. It is a boolean to trigger some kind of behaviour.